# Virtualbox - How to use virtual machines have already installed (Windows) on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have just installed some virtual machines on Windows and now I want to use them on Ubuntu too. How can I do it ? Somebody can help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Before I write an answer: Can you WRITE on the Windows NTFS partition from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Download the .deb file for virtual box from here and install it by simply double click on it.
http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Answer (score 0):

You can install VirtualBox OSE (Open Source Edition) on Ubuntu by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose
```

From there, the process of setting up a new VM is the same as it is in Windows.